# Show that the set $M$ is a 2-dimensional $C^1$-manifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Show that the set $M:=${$(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|x^3+y^3+z^3=1$}$\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a 2-dimensional $C^1$-manifold. I don't really understand the definition of a manifold so I have no idea what I'd have to show. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This shows no effort at all. Have you at least tried to look up the definition that you are supposed to use?

Comment: Yes and I do not understand it, therefore my question.

Comment: So what is the definition? What part don't you understand?

Comment: The definition is that on a local level it should look like a 2 dimensional euclidian space. And what I don't understand is how I'd show that

Comment: That's not precise enough. You should give a more precise definition if you want to really prove anything.

Comment: Do you know a better definition? I am on here for help, not because I know what to do.

Comment: What definition did your lecturer give you? If you're not following a lecture, then what source material are you using?

Comment: I am using advanced calculus of several variables from edwards. we are at chapter 3 paragraph 4. The definition they give here is: a k-dimensional manifold in R^n is a set M that looks locally like the graph of a mapping from R^k to Rn-k. That is every point of M lies in an open subsut V of R^n s.t. P=V (intersection) M is a k dimensional patch.

Comment: But I just figured there'd be like a plan I could follow, like you have to show these 3 things and than it's a manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking at the 1973 edition of the text and it seems that the actual definition on a manifold is hidden away on page 110 in the second paragraph from the bottom. This is in chapter 2 section 5. I found the definition a little cryptic, so I sympathize with your confusion and will say a couple of words about it. Edwards defines a manifold as something that is locally the graph of a differentiable function. So, if you are working with this definition here is an outline of what a proof should look like. Basically, for each point $x\in M\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, you need to find a subset of $P$ of $M$ containing $x$, and an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and a differentiable function $h: U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$, such that $P$ is the graph of $h$. Note that the graph can be identified with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. However, it might not happen that $P$ is not literally the graph of the function, for example consider a vertical line in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is why the definition allows you to permute the coordinates. In order to do the problem you have given, I recommend that you closely study the definition and make sure you understand all the terms in it. Then examine the worked examples to see what a proof looks like when written down.

Comment: Thanks Julius, I was able to prove it using theorem 4.1 from chapter 3.5 from that book.